# How to rewrite inner img tags source with new image path using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to rewrite image path of following img tag with new image path while click on span element

```
<span id="cc-element-1">
    <img src="http://localhost/example/orig/abc.jpg"/>
</span>
```

Expected result as follows,

```
<span id="cc-element-1">
    <img src="http://localhost/example/cloned/abc.jpg"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#cc-element-1').click(function() {
    var $img = $(this).children('img');
    $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace(/orig/, 'cloned'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If doing a read-modify-write on an attribute you should use the [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) based version of `.attr` over the code given by @Sahil:

```
$('#cc-element-1').click(function() {
    var $img = $(this).children('img');
    $img.attr('src', function(index, val) {
        return val.replace(/orig/, 'cloned'));
    });
});
```

This avoids the need to call `$img.attr(src)` twice - once to read and once to write.

It's therefore more efficient, particularly so if the original selector is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cc-element-1 > img").click(function() {$(this).attr('src', 'http://localhost/example/cloned/abc.jpg')})
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var newSrc = 'http://localhost/example/cloned/abc.jpg';

$('span#cc-element-1').click(function(){
     $(this).children('img').attr('src', newSrc);   
});
```

See an example here:

[http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/FdgzJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/FdgzJ/3/)